# SQL Select two records if they have certain time difference of column A and have same column B value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 14000 records in my sql table. They have columns `ID`, `test_subject_id` and `date_created`. I want to fetch all the records that have been created within a time difference of `3` minutes(difference in date_created values) and both records should have the same `test_subject_id`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a self join, I assume inner join is what will work for you:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.date_created, b.ID, b.date_created
FROM accounts a
INNER JOIN accounts b
    ON a.test_subject_id = b.test_subject_id
    AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,a.date_created,b.date_created) = 3
```

Note: `TIMESTAMPDIFF` is used assuming `date_created` has type `datetime`, details [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tablename t1
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM tablename t2
  WHERE t2.test_subject_id = t1.test_subject_id 
  AND ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, t1.date_created, t2.date_created)) <= 180
)
ORDER BY t1.test_subject_id, t1.date_created;
```